# Send literal string from python-vim script to a tmux pane

Tags: python, vim, tmux

I am using Vim (8.0) and tmux (2.3) together in the following way: In a tmux session I have a window split to 2 panes, one pane has some text file open in Vim, the other pane has some program to which I want to send lines of text. A typical use case is sending lines from a Python script to IPython session running in the other pane.

I am doing this by a Vim script which uses python, code snippet example (assuming the target tmux pane is 0):

```
py import vim
python << endpython
cmd = "print 1+2"
vim_cmd = "silent !tmux send-keys -t 0 -l \"" + cmd + "\"" # -l for literal
vim.command(vim_cmd)
endpython
```

This works well, except for when `cmd` has some characters which has to be escaped, like `%`, `#`, `$`, etc. The `cmd` variable is read from the current line in the text file opened in Vim, so I can do something like `cmd = cmd.replace('%', '\%')` etc., but this has 2 disadvantages: first, I don't know all the vim characters which have to be escaped, so it has been trial and error up until now, and second, the characters `"` is not escaped properly - that is in the string Vim gets, the `"` just disappears, even if I do `cmd = cmd.replace('"', '\"')`.
So, is there a general way to tell Vim to not interpret anything, just get a raw string and send it as is? If not, why is the `"` not escaped properly?

Comment: May want to look into using Tim Pope's [tbone.vim plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-tbone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Vimscript

You're looking for the `shellescape()` function. If you use the `:!` Vim command, the `{special}` argument needs to be 1.

```
silent execute '!tmux send-keys -t 0 -l ' . shellescape(cmd, 1)
```

But as you're not interested in (displaying) the shell output, and do not need to interact with the launched script, I would switch from `:!` to the lower-level `system()` command.

```
call system('tmux send-keys -t 0 -l ' . shellescape(cmd))
```

#### Python

The use of Python (instead of pure Vimscript) doesn't have any benefits (at least in the small snippet in your question). Instead, if you embed the Python `cmd` variable in a Vimscript expression, now you also need a Python function to escape the value as a Vimscript string (something like `'%s'" % str(cmd).replace("'", "''"))`). Alternatively, you could maintain the value in a Vim variable, and access it from Python via `vim.vars`.

Comment: When I use vim variable, I still have to manually escape a `;` regardless if it is defined by `let a=";"` or `let a=';'`. Why is that?

Comment: Ok I get it, that's tmux/shell behavior, I guess the shell interprets characters like `;` or `!`. Oddly, if I add a space after these characters they are sent ok.

Comment: Sorry, last remark/Q: if I use `shellcmd(getline('.'))` all is ok, except for a single `;` (unless it has space after it, `; ` is sent ok)