# Key bindings to send lines of test code with tmux+vim?

Tags: python, bash, vim, ide, tmux

I am trying to create an ide-like setup with **tmux + vim**. I've seen a lot written about this on the internet, but I've been unable to figure out how to do one critical thing: execute test lines of code.

For example, you may create a tmux session with a vim pane for writing code and a python pane for executing tests, like so:

```sh
# Create a new Tmux session.
session="ide"
tmux start-server
tmux new-session -d -s $session -n ide

# Split the pane horizontally and launch vim.
tmux selectp -t 1
tmux splitw -v -p 50
tmux selectp -t 1
tmux send-keys "vim" C-m

# Enter insert mode and start coding...
tmux send-keys "i"
tmux send-keys "print('hello world')" C-m

# Select the second pane and launch python.
tmux selectp -t 2
tmux send-keys "python" C-m

# Attach to tmux session.
tmux attach -t ide
```

So, I am aware of how you might use `tmux send-keys` or tmux's command mode (`<prefix> :`) to send commands to another pane. However, I'd like to make a vim key binding that copies whatever line I'm on and sends this to the opposite pane in a couple of quick keystrokes.

If you have some magic sauce, I'd be grateful if you could share!

Answer (score 2):

I think https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime is what you are be looking for.

Once installed and configured (`tmux` is not the default used, `screen` is), you can execute the text under the cursor with `<C-c><C-c>`.

**The following worked for me**:

- Install Vim-slime. I'm using Vundle, so I added the following to my `.vimrc`:
  `Plugin 'jpalardy/vim-slime'`, and ran `:PluginInstall` in vim.
- Configure slime for tmux by adding the following to your `.vimrc`:
  `let g:slime_target = "tmux"`
- Try sending a line with vim-slime with the default key-binding (`C-c C-c`). Vim-Slime should prompt you for Tmux's socket and target pane. 
  I found Tmux's socket with:
  `echo $TMUX | cut -f1 -d','`.
- Alternatively, you can use `:SlimeConfig`.
- Now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like vim-slime is the way to go.

But updating this in-case it is useful for others.

You could make a mapping as follows.
The change from `-t +` to `-t .+` should cause tmux to paste to an alternate pane

`vnoremap <leader>tp :call system('tmux send-keys -t .+ -l ' . shellescape(join([getline("."), "\n"])) )<CR>`

Reference:
[Send literal string from python-vim script to a tmux pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632209/send-literal-string-from-python-vim-script-to-a-tmux-pane?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks Caqe. I appreciate this solutions simplicity. I tried for a couple minutes to get this to work, but was unsuccessful. Not sure why, but this command seems to paste whatever line I was on back into the vim editor. But, Vim-Slime seems to be working for me.

Comment: Okay, sounds like Vim-Slime is the way to go.  It probably handles more edge cases.  I updated the solution with -t .+ which should fix the problem you were seeing, but still doesn't handle the case when a multi-line python cmd needs one final newline sent over in order to run